# Cx_Oracle - How to specify a query with a double ordered output

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I'm working on a Cx_Oracle 11g database: I'm wondering if it's possible have two innested different types of `order by` in output from a table. I mean, suppose the columns are `name` , `timestamp` and `value` and I need output looks like:

```
nameA - timestamp1 - value
nameA - timestamp2 - value
nameA - timestamp3 - value
nameB - timestamp1 - value
nameB - timestamp2 - value
nameB - timestamp3 - value
```

Where the principal order is by `name`, and `timestamp` is ordered for every different `name`. How can I do?

Comment: Doesn't `order by name, timestamp` work in Cx_Oracle? What error do you get?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, it works. I didn't know that, thanks. Does the order in which column names appear in the clause, determine the way query works?

Comment: It will order by `name` and then within those by `timestamp`, which is what you want. The order the columns appear in the list does matter, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF20039):

> You can specify multiple expressions in the *order_by_clause*. Oracle Database first sorts rows based on their values for the first expression. Rows with the same value for the first expression are then sorted based on their values for the second expression, and so on

So in your case just doing:

```
order by name, timestamp
```

in your query will do what you describe.